# How to applied texture to selected object?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I tried following tutorial on youtube

link:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHLT5Xh_tzQ&list=PLWYj1pF7QxoR32dK6425Dd2I0BFgUt0E_&index=19

at 4:20
the texture different from what i got (link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw6Zp.jpg )
how to applied texture on selected object (vertical pole)and not all object?

Is there any proper way to texture properly?
Blender version i used: 2.81a

Answer (score 1):

The original UV of a model is dependent on how you modeled your mesh, it's expected that a UV can look different from your tutorial at the start of UVing.
Also, before UVing a mesh it's a good idea to apply any transformations, they can stretch or have weird effects on you're UVs if you ever get that issue.